# julia find in matrix with (row,col) instead of index

Tags: matrix, find, julia

In Julia you can find the coordinates of elements in a matrix via:

```
julia> find( x -> x == 2, [ 1 2 3; 2 3 4; 1 0 2] )
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 4
 9
```

These values are correct but I would prefer that I would get the (row,col) tuples instead.

```
(1,2)
(2,1)
(3,3)
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this in Julia?

Comment: Note this question is no longer relevant since Julia 1.0, so don't be misled by the answers if you're using modern Julia. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70409056/3697870) for what happens now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is an inbuilt way to do it, but here is a function to do it

```
function findmat(f, A::AbstractMatrix)
  m,n = size(A)
  out = (Int,Int)[]
  for i in 1:m, j in 1:n
    f(A[i,j]) && push!(out,(i,j))
  end
  out
end
```

e.g.

```
julia> findmat(x->x==2, [ 1 2 3; 2 3 4; 1 0 2] )
3-element Array{(Int64,Int64),1}:
 (1,2)
 (2,1)
 (3,3)
```

If a large number of items satisfy the condition it might be more efficient to do it in two passes, but I doubt it.

**Edit:**

For newer versions of Julia replace

```
out = (Int,Int)[]
```

with

```
out = Tuple{Int, Int}[]
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else finds this you can now use:

```
ind2sub(a, index)
```

It returns a tuple of subscripts into array `a` corresponding to the linear index `index`

Comment: that's not what is sought by OP, they want to search by value

Comment: where is this ind2sub function ?

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing that I can find in the Julia standard library is `findn` :

```
julia> A = [1 2 3; 2 3 4; 1 0 2]
3x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 2  3  4
 1  0  2

julia> findn(A .== 2)
([2,1,3],[1,2,3])
```

This gives a tuple of vectors instead of a vector of tuples, though.

Another thing to note is that the match at `(2,1)` is reported before the one at `(1,2)`. This is because arrays in Julia are stored in column major order, so scanning the array `A` in storage order will look at the position `(2,1)` before `(1,2)`.

Comment: ```findn( [2 2; 2 2] .== 2) != [(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)]```

Answer (score 2):

if you wish to avoid defining "new" functions, perhaps:

```
collect(zip(ind2sub((3,3),find( x -> x == 2, [ 1 2 3; 2 3 4; 1 0 2] ))...))
```

is what you are looking for. the (3,3) is implicit in the size of the matrix. if the matrix was given by a variable it would look more natural with a `size(M)`

Answer (score 2):

on julia 1.7, `find` does not exist (it was deprecated on julia 1.0), `findall` is the equivalent that gives the same result as the original question.
On matrices, findall will return `CartesianIndex` locations:

```
julia> idx = findall( x -> x == 2, [ 1 2 3; 2 3 4; 1 0 2])
3-element Vector{CartesianIndex{2}}:
 CartesianIndex(2, 1)
 CartesianIndex(1, 2)
 CartesianIndex(3, 3)

julia> ans[1][1]
2
```