# How can I find a value's location in a matrix in Julia?

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia

I was using `find` with a 3D matrix `A` like this:

```
julia> find(A.==1)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
1
234
4567
```

Julia gives me the location as an index instead of as an array of indices. For example, it returns 234 instead of (1,2,1).

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196733/julia-find-in-matrix-with-row-col-instead-of-index), but my matrix is very large and has a shape of (360,360,360). I can't use the method suggested there.

I tried to study its index pattern and transform it using a function that I coded:

```
function cmf_p(matrix)
      for a=1:length(matrix);
          aa=matrix[a]
          rd_u_m=ceil(aa/(360^2))
          rd_d_m=floor(aa/(360^2)-1)
          rd_d_t=(aa-rd_d_m*360)/360^2   
          rd_d_p=aa-rd_d_m*360^2-floor(rd_d_t)*360
          println(rd_u_m);
          println(ceil(rd_d_t)*360);
          println(ceil(aa-rd_d_m*360^2-floor(rd_d_t)*360))
      end    
end
```

But it gives me the wrong result.

How can I use the index and transform it to the location I want?

Comment: does my post answer your question? If so, please accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `ind2sub`:

```
julia> A = eye(3)
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0

julia> inds = find(A.==1.0)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 5
 9

julia> [ind2sub(size(A), ind) for ind in inds]
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 (1,1)
 (2,2)
 (3,3)
```

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help